# Android Studio 3 emulator fails - Lunux Mint

Tags: display-driver, android-studio

I have a new installation of Android Studio 3 on Linux Mint. When trying to run on an emulator, it fails with the following errors in the log:

> 7:00 PM Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
>
> 7:00 PM Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
>
> 7:00 PM Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
>
> 7:00 PM Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
>
> 7:00 PM Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>
> 7:00 PM Emulator: X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer
>   parameter out of range for operation)
>
> 7:00 PM Emulator: Major opcode of failed request: 155 (GLX)
>
> 7:00 PM Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request: 24
>   (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
>
> 7:00 PM Emulator: Value in failed request: 0x0
>
> 7:00 PM Emulator: Serial number of failed request: 58
>
> 7:00 PM Emulator: Current serial number in output stream: 59
>
> 7:00 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

It looks like Android Studio 3 is trying to use the default X.Org Nouveau display driver. However, I am using the NVIDIA binary driver 384.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Look in the **Android Virtual Device (AVD)** area from within the **Virtual Device Configuration** and in the "*Emulated Performance*" section change the `Graphics` field to a value of "**Software" and see if that helps resolve the problem. Check this post too with screen shots and another path type solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653391/cannot-launch-avd-in-emulator-android-studio/37679624